# Making a VDI image bootable for VirtualBox

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, boot, dd

I created a disk image of a Ubuntu (12.04) system by using

```
dd if=/dev/sda6 of=xxx.img
```

The VDI image was created by  using

```
vboxmanage clonehd xxx.img xxx.vdi --format VDI
```

When I create a new VM in VirtualBox and use the created VDI as mass storage the system does not boot because VirtualBox finds no bootable medium:

```
FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.
```

What else do I need to do in order to make the VDI image bootable?

Answer (score 2):

I did it in the following way:

```
~$ fallocate -l xxsizeM xxx.img
~$ fdisk xxx.img
```

Partition as needed and don't forget to leave some space at the beginning and set a partition bootable flag using 'a' and a partition number.

```
~$ losetup -f --show xxx.img
```

Will connect your file to a loop device `/dev/loopY`. Remember that Y number.

```
~$ kpartx -a /dev/loopY
```

Now you have access to this disk as if it was a normal HD through `/dev/mapper/loopYpZ` where Z are your partitions as you set them up using `fdisk`.

`dd` your ubuntu to the bootable partition (i would run `mkfs.xxfstype /dev/mapper/loopYpZ` first just in case).

```
~$ dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/loopY conv=notrunc
```

to clone your mbr contents into the image's mbr.

```
~$ sync; kpartx -d /dev/loopY; losetup -d /dev/loopY
```

Convert your image to vdi/vmdk as you did, and now it should work for you...
Hope that helps...